# ReactJS - firebase how query a record with particular .key

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have here a screen shot of the object I want to retrieve from firebase.

[image]

This is how I do it

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        items: []
    };
}
componentWillMount(){
    this.firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://sweltering-heat-7923.firebaseio.com/contact/-KF1XUgOvcrybku8Q52s');
    this.firebaseRef.once("value", function (snapshot){

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            console.log(data.val());
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

I got this response

[image]

Which is not what I want, I was expecting something like this

```
{
   object{ address1: '', address2: '', postalCode: ''}
   email: "",
   firstName:"ohoh",
   gender:"",
   id:1460331472003,
   lastName: "asd",
   phone: ""
}
```

How would you do it?

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over all the child nodes of `contact/-KF1XUgOvcrybku8Q52s` and logging them one by one. To get the full object, use `snapshot.val()` instead of `snapshot.forEach(...)`:

```
this.firebaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```